# Cannot run Ant command with JDK 9 on Windows 7

Tags: java, ant, java-9

1. Cooja is a tool of embedded operation system--Contiki.

   - and here is the [source codes of Contiki-os](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki).
2. Cooja uses Ant command to run(at the directory of Cooja,there has a build.xml file).

   - I'm using Ant with version of 1.10.1.
3. Ant is a java-based tool and it needs a JDK installed in system.

   - I'm using JDK-9 to run with Ant.
4. when I using 'ant run' command at the directory of Cooja the problem comes,the cmd.exe where I use 'ant run' command to run Cooja says

> 'java.xml.bind is not visible' and 'package javax.xml.bind is declared in module java.xml.bind, which is not in the module graph'.

5. Then I search for answer with google and I understand that this problem caused by the new module system of JDK-9.

   - here is the [link of the document](http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/modules/root-modules/) which introduces the module system and there occur the same problem with mine and elaborate why it occurs.
   - but the document fixes the problem using javac command through the option '--add-modules' and I don't know how to fix mine when using Ant command there doesn't have such option.
6. If I use the JDK-8 to run with Ant the problem can be fixed because the version of JDK doesn't have module system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ant buildfile should be invoking the Java compiler using the [javac](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) task. In order to update it with the --add-modules option, search for the appropriate javac invocation and embed the option as a nested compilerarg, e.g.:

```
<javac srcdir="src" destdir="classes">
    <compilerarg arg="--add-modules java.xml.bind"/>
</javac>
```

Comment: Yes,your method makes my program work!
And I add codes to build.xml file just a little different from yours.here is codes:

`<javac ...>
 <compilerarg line="--add-modules java.xml.bind"/>
</javac>`

And before this problem get solved all I tried to do is to add some parameters like 'modulepath' or 'modulepathref' to the javac task of build.xml file,but unfortunately these way can not take effect.
Any way,thank you very much.

Comment: Also see https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-9-migration-guide/#Dependencies-On-Java-EE-Modules. The ideal solution is to have whatever Java code you're building transformed into a module and add 'java.xml.bind' as a required module in the module declaration. This may not feasible if the code you're building is a third-party, in that case the '--add-modules' can be used.

Comment: Keep in mind that java.xml.bind module is deprecated for removal from Java SE. So some future Java SE / JDK release will not include the java.xml.bind module. So a better medium term solution is to move to the standalone version of JAXB. More on this in JDK 9 Migration Guide (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm).